# Is "doing a dance" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is "doing a dance" idiomatic? I am thinking this isn't idiomatic, but I am not sure. Is it the case? I think I have heard it being used, but I think it's not idiomatic and there are better ways to say it.

For example:

> He did the Gangnam Style dance.
>
> He's doing the Gangnam Style dance.

Comment: If you judge by the appearances of the phrase on Google Books Ngram Viewer, the answer is most certainly YES.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doing+a+dance%2Chaving+a+dance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely!

> Everybody’s doin’ a brand new dance now.
>
> Come on baby, do the loco-motion.

And many others that while not explicitly using that precise phrase demonstrate that “doing” is certainly something that applies to dances. For example:

> Any time you're Lambeth way
>
> Any evening, any day,
>
> You'll find us all
>
> Doin' the Lambeth walk.…

Or

> You clap your hands
>
> And you swing out wide
>
> Do the susie q
>
> Mix in a step or two
>
> Put 'em all together
>
> And you're doin the jive